# Receiving all values in JSON php

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{

"thirdPartyForms": [
    {
        "driverAddress": "Adress",
        "PolicyOwner": "nimo",
        "driverInsCompany": "lkjlkj",
        "driverName": "drvivcer name",
        "agentPhone": "kj",
        "carLicensing": "lkjkl",
        "driverId": "0980980980",
        "driverPhone": "098908098",
        "agentName": "j"
    },
    {
        "driverAddress": "",
        "PolicyOwner": "",
        "driverInsCompany": "",
        "driverName": "driver 5",
        "agentPhone": "",
        "carLicensing": "",
        "driverId": "",
        "driverPhone": "",
        "agentName": ""
    }
],
"personalForm": {
    "insDriverName": "",
    "insCarLicensing": "",
    "insId": "039956974",
    "insName": "bnrus",
    "insDriverId": "",
    "insPhone": ""
}
}
```

I tried to save all fields using this function I wrote:

```
    function JSONForm()
    {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
            $d = stripslashes($_POST['formJSON']);
        }else{
            $d = $_POST['formJSON'];
        }
        $d = json_decode($d,true);

    $myArray = array();

    foreach($d as $item)
    {

        foreach($item as $key => $value)
        {
            $myArray[$key] = $value."\n";
        }
    }

 }
```

I'm not getting all the fields (i'm getting 'array' instead the fields). This is my output:

```
0 => Array
1 => Array
insDriverName => 
insCarLicensing => 
insId => 039956974
insName => bnrus
insDriverId => 
insPhone =>
```

How can I improve my function so that it will work?
That means -> i'm not able to save all the values inside the JSONArray (output line 1 & 2).

Comment: You concat $value with "\n", it's a string operation, hence you end up with a string.
I suggest you to print_r your $d you'll see how to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Solution**

Moved to the top for clarity.

Try this to recursively flatten the array

```
$d = json_decode($json, true);

$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($d));
foreach($it as $k => $v) {
  echo $k . " is " . $v . "\n";
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Your code is working as expected, you cannot `echo` or `print` an array, the data is there. Instead do this;

```
function JSONForm()
{
   if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
       $d = stripslashes($_POST['formJSON']);
   }else{
       $d = $_POST['formJSON'];
   }
   $d = json_decode($d,true);

   // A var_dump here will show you the true values of all of the
   // decoded array
   var_dump($d);

   // In fact you do not need to iterate over the array, at all
   // because the variable $d already contains all the json data

   $myArray = array();

   foreach($d as $item)
   {
    foreach($item as $key => $value)
    {
        // This will output all the array using print_r, setting the 2nd
        // parameter to be true will return the output, rather than print it
        $myArray[$key] = print_r($value, true)."\n";
    }
   }
 }
```

**EDIT**

This is your data;

```
// thirdPartyForms is an array, it has no keys so the array will be
// zero indexed
"thirdPartyForms": [
    { // this is position zero
        "driverAddress": "Adress",
        "PolicyOwner": "nimo",
        "driverInsCompany": "lkjlkj",
        "driverName": "drvivcer name",
        "agentPhone": "kj",
        "carLicensing": "lkjkl",
        "driverId": "0980980980",
        "driverPhone": "098908098",
        "agentName": "j"
    },
    { // this is position one
        "driverAddress": "",
        "PolicyOwner": "",
        "driverInsCompany": "",
        "driverName": "driver 5",
        "agentPhone": "",
        "carLicensing": "",
        "driverId": "",
        "driverPhone": "",
        "agentName": ""
    }
],
"personalForm": { 
    "insDriverName": "",
    "insCarLicensing": "",
    "insId": "039956974",
    "insName": "bnrus",
    "insDriverId": "",
    "insPhone": ""
}
```

So you can then access the array using numbered indices;

```
// This will give you 'Adress'
echo $d["thirdPartyForms"][0]["driverAddress"]

// This will give you 'bnrus'
echo $d["personalForm"]["insName"];
```

Using `var_dump($d)` will make this much easier as you can see the make up of the array more clearly.

Using a loop;

```
foreach($d as $key => $data)
{
   // This will output the data for a key, note that var_dump will
   // output an array just fine
   var_dump($data);

   // The issue you have is that $data could be a string or another array,
   // Because your first element "thirdPartyForms" is an array of arrays
   // The second element "personalForm" is an array of strings

   // Check if its an array and if so iterate again
   if(is_array($data))
   {
      echo $key . " is an array\n";

      // Here we loop over the array again, note that if you have arrays in a
      // array then you will need a recursive function
      foreach($data as $k => $value)
      {
         echo $k . " within an array is " . $value . "\n";         
      }
   }
   else
   {
      echo $key . " is not an array, it is " . $data . "\n";
   }  
}
```

Comment: and how can i access all  $myArray values (even the 'array' values)?

Comment: Jake N: 10x. But i don't want to access it one by one.
I want to save all of them in an array to to access them by foreach loop

Comment: Hmmm my code didn't work as expected because you have nested arrays, but it should show my point?

Comment: Thats where i'm stuck. Beacause of the nested arrays. i'm trying to insert them in one array so i can access ALL fields by simple foreach.

Comment: Mark as the 'answer' ;-)